# Разноцветный ProgressBar

Tags: android

Увидел на сайте [Google Диск](https://www.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/drive/) при загрузке просмотра файла модный круглый `ProgressBar`, который переливается четырьмя цветами.

По-другому: `SwipeRefreshLayout` крутит такой `ProgressBar` при свайпе вниз. И крутится он в белом кружке. А нужен отдельный, независимый от свайпов, обычный `View` и без бэкграунда.

Вопрос: Как реализовать такой `ProgressBar` в андроид приложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не уверен какой именно `ProgressBar` имеется ввиду.

Вот бибиотеки, которые реализую разнообразные `ProgressBar` в стиле Google:

- [GoogleProgressBar](https://github.com/jpardogo/GoogleProgressBar)
- [SmoothProgressBar](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar)

Там же можно найти их реализации.

Вот к примеру `ProgressBar`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его реализация:

```
public class ChromeFloatingCirclesDrawable extends Drawable implements Drawable.Callback {

// constants
private static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;
private static final int CENT_LEVEL = MAX_LEVEL / 2;
private static final int MID_LEVEL = CENT_LEVEL / 2;
private static final int ALPHA_OPAQUE = 255;
private static final int ACCELERATION_LEVEL = 2;

// default
private int mAlpha = ALPHA_OPAQUE;
private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

// points and paints
private Point[] mArrowPoints;
private Paint mPaint1;
private Paint mPaint2;
private Paint mPaint3;
private Paint mPaint4;
private double unit;
private int width, x_beg, y_beg, x_end, y_end, offset;

// speed related
private int acceleration = ACCELERATION_LEVEL;
private double distance = 0.5 * ACCELERATION_LEVEL * MID_LEVEL * MID_LEVEL;
private double max_speed; // set in setAcceleration(...);
private double offsetPercentage;

// top color var
private int colorSign;
private ProgressStates currentProgressStates = ProgressStates.GREEN_TOP;

private enum ProgressStates {
    GREEN_TOP,
    YELLOW_TOP,
    RED_TOP,
    BLUE_TOP
}

public ChromeFloatingCirclesDrawable(int[] colors) {
    initCirclesProgress(colors);
}

private void initCirclesProgress(int[] colors) {
    //init Paint colors
    initColors(colors);

    // init alpha and color filter
    setAlpha(mAlpha);
    setColorFilter(mColorFilter);

    // offset percentage
    setAcceleration(ACCELERATION_LEVEL);
    offsetPercentage = 0;

    // init colorSign
    colorSign = 1; // |= 1, |= 2, |= 4, |= 8 --> 0xF
}

private void initColors(int[] colors) {
    // red circle, left up
    mPaint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint1.setColor(colors[0]);
    mPaint1.setAntiAlias(true);

    // blue circle, right down
    mPaint2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint2.setColor(colors[1]);
    mPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);

    // yellow circle, left down
    mPaint3 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint3.setColor(colors[2]);
    mPaint3.setAntiAlias(true);

    // green circle, right up
    mPaint4 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint4.setColor(colors[3]);
    mPaint4.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    measureCircleProgress(bounds.width(), bounds.height());
}

@Override
protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
    // calc one offset data is enough
    // 0.5 * a * t^2 / mCenterPoint.x = level / sideLevel
    // t from 0 to 10,000, so divided into 4 parts.
    // the ACCELERATION_LEVEL defines how many divisions in 10000 levels
    level %= MAX_LEVEL / acceleration;

    final int temp_level = level % (MID_LEVEL / acceleration);
    final int ef_width = (int)(unit * 3.0); // effective width
    if(level < CENT_LEVEL / acceleration) { // go
        if(level < MID_LEVEL / acceleration) {
            // set colorSign
            if(colorSign == 0xF) {
                changeTopColor();
                colorSign = 1;
            }
            // from beg to mid
            offsetPercentage = 0.5 * acceleration * temp_level * temp_level / distance;
            offset = (int)(offsetPercentage * ef_width / 2); // x and y direction offset
        }
        else {
            // set colorSign
            colorSign |= 2;
            // from mid to end
            offsetPercentage = (max_speed * temp_level
                    - 0.5 * acceleration * temp_level * temp_level) / distance
                    + 1.0;
            offset = (int)(offsetPercentage * ef_width / 2); // x and y direction offset
        }
    }
    else { // back
        if(level < (CENT_LEVEL + MID_LEVEL) / acceleration) {
            // set colorSign
            if(colorSign == 0x3) {
                changeTopColor();
                colorSign |= 4;
            }
            // from end to mid
            offsetPercentage = 0.5 * acceleration * temp_level * temp_level  / distance;
            offset = (int)(ef_width - offsetPercentage * ef_width / 2); // x and y direction offset
        }
        else {
            // set colorSign
            colorSign |= 8;
            // from mid to beg
            offsetPercentage = (max_speed * temp_level
                    - 0.5 * acceleration * temp_level * temp_level) / distance
                    + 1.0;
            offsetPercentage = offsetPercentage == 1.0 ? 2.0 : offsetPercentage;
            offset = (int)(ef_width - offsetPercentage * ef_width / 2); // x and y direction offset
        }
    }

    mArrowPoints[0].set((int)unit+x_beg+offset, (int)unit+y_beg+offset); // mPaint1, left up
    mArrowPoints[1].set((int)(unit*4.0)+x_beg-offset, (int)(unit*4.0)+y_beg-offset); // mPaint2, right down
    mArrowPoints[2].set((int)unit+x_beg+offset, (int)(unit*4.0)+y_beg-offset); // mPaint3, left down
    mArrowPoints[3].set((int)(unit*4.0)+x_beg-offset, (int)unit+y_beg+offset); // mPaint4, right up

    return true;
}

private void changeTopColor() {
    switch(currentProgressStates){
        case GREEN_TOP:
            currentProgressStates = ProgressStates.YELLOW_TOP;
            break;
        case YELLOW_TOP:
            currentProgressStates = ProgressStates.RED_TOP;
            break;
        case RED_TOP:
            currentProgressStates = ProgressStates.BLUE_TOP;
            break;
        case BLUE_TOP:
            currentProgressStates = ProgressStates.GREEN_TOP;
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw circles
    if(currentProgressStates != ProgressStates.RED_TOP)
        canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[0].x, mArrowPoints[0].y, (float)unit, mPaint1);
    if(currentProgressStates != ProgressStates.BLUE_TOP)
        canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[1].x, mArrowPoints[1].y, (float)unit, mPaint2);
    if(currentProgressStates != ProgressStates.YELLOW_TOP)
        canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[2].x, mArrowPoints[2].y, (float)unit, mPaint3);
    if(currentProgressStates != ProgressStates.GREEN_TOP)
        canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[3].x, mArrowPoints[3].y, (float)unit, mPaint4);

    // draw the top one
    switch(currentProgressStates){
        case GREEN_TOP:
            canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[3].x, mArrowPoints[3].y, (float)unit, mPaint4);
            break;
        case YELLOW_TOP:
            canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[2].x, mArrowPoints[2].y, (float)unit, mPaint3);
            break;
        case RED_TOP:
            canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[0].x, mArrowPoints[0].y, (float)unit, mPaint1);
            break;
        case BLUE_TOP:
            canvas.drawCircle(mArrowPoints[1].x, mArrowPoints[1].y, (float)unit, mPaint2);
            break;
    }
}

private void measureCircleProgress(int width, int height) {
    // get min edge as width
    if(width > height) {
        // use height
        this.width = height - 1; // minus 1 to avoid "3/2=1"
        x_beg = (width - height) / 2 + 1;
        y_beg = 1;
        x_end = x_beg + this.width;
        y_end = this.width;
    }
    else {
        //use width
        this.width = width - 1;
        x_beg = 1;
        y_beg = (height - width) / 2 + 1;
        x_end = this.width;
        y_end = y_beg + this.width;
    }
    unit = (double)this.width / 5.0;

    // init the original position, and then set position by offsets
    mArrowPoints = new Point[4];
    mArrowPoints[0] = new Point((int)unit+x_beg, (int)unit+y_beg); // mPaint1, left up
    mArrowPoints[1] = new Point((int)(unit*4.0)+x_beg, (int)(unit*4.0)+y_beg); // mPaint2, right down
    mArrowPoints[2] = new Point((int)unit+x_beg, (int)(unit*4.0)+y_beg); // mPaint3, left down
    mArrowPoints[3] = new Point((int)(unit*4.0)+x_beg, (int)unit+y_beg); // mPaint4, right up
}

public void setAcceleration(int acceleration) {
    this.acceleration = acceleration;
    distance = 0.5 * acceleration * (MID_LEVEL / acceleration) * (MID_LEVEL / acceleration);
    max_speed = acceleration * (MID_LEVEL / acceleration);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    mPaint1.setAlpha(alpha);
    mPaint2.setAlpha(alpha);
    mPaint3.setAlpha(alpha);
    mPaint4.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    mColorFilter = cf;
    mPaint1.setColorFilter(cf);
    mPaint2.setColorFilter(cf);
    mPaint3.setColorFilter(cf);
    mPaint4.setColorFilter(cf);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}

@Override
public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
    final Callback callback = getCallback();
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.invalidateDrawable(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
    final Callback callback = getCallback();
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.scheduleDrawable(this, what, when);
    }
}

@Override
public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
    final Callback callback = getCallback();
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.unscheduleDrawable(this, what);
    }
}

public static class Builder {
    private int[] mColors;

    public Builder(Context context){
        initDefaults(context);
        return;
    }

    private void initDefaults(Context context) {
        //Default values
        mColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.google_colors);
        return;
    }

    public Builder colors(int[] colors) {
        if (colors == null || colors.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your color array must contains at least 4 values");
        }

        mColors = colors;
        return this;
    }

    public Drawable build() {
        return new ChromeFloatingCirclesDrawable(mColors);
    }
  }
}
```